# Not able to open eclipse. Showing error has occured

Tags: eclipse

[image: Error Message]

i used to work with eclipse daily. Suddenly i am getting this error popup while opening the eclipse. But the same is working when i ran this eclipse as a administrator. But every time it is difficult to run as a administrator i want to run as a normal user only.

Inspecting the log file yields:

> !ENTRY com.esirisc.toolchain.help.hover 2 0 2018-09-03 10:26:24.878 !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.esirisc.toolchain.help.hover [435] Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover; bundle-version="1.2.0"
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.libstdcxx 2 0 2018-09-03 10:26:24.879 !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.libstdcxx [438] Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover; bundle-version="1.0.1" !MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

If any one know about this let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you even read this alert? What is in mentioned file?

Comment: Read the log file and show us what it says.

Comment: !ENTRY com.esirisc.toolchain.help.hover 2 0 2018-09-03 10:26:24.878
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.esirisc.toolchain.help.hover [435]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover; bundle-version="1.2.0"
!ENTRY org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.libstdcxx 2 0 2018-09-03 10:26:24.879
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover.libstdcxx [438]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.cdt.libhover; bundle-version="1.0.1"

!MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Not able to attach complete log file but this is the main part

Comment: Would be better to add your log file to your original question so that its not formatted into a single line

Comment: Is the same workspace when you open it as administrator as well as common user?

Comment: yes. When i open eclipse icon on desktop itself showing error. Same eclipse working when i run as as administrator